# how to get a reference to python caller of a C api function

Tags: python, c

I am implementing an embedded python interpreter following https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html

There is a way for me to easily create my own APIs to my C program so that a user can call my own internal C functions from a python script.

This all works fine, but I would like to be able to know from which script the function got called. Every function must have these parameters according to manual:

```
static PyObject *SomeApiFunction(PyObject *self, PyObject *args)
```

But the manual doesn't explain what `self` is so I assumed that self is a reference to module that called the function, which was probably wrong. I tried to call `PyModule_GetName` on self and it returned the internal name of my application which I set during initialization (using `PyModule_Create`).

Is there a way to recognize which module called my C function?

Answer (score 0):

If you were doing this in Python, you could use the following line:

```
module_path = sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_filename
```

You might be able to do something similar in the C API, but I have never worked with it.